# Using nmcli to set subnet mask and gateway IP

Tags: centos, networking, rhel, ip, webserver

The [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Networking Guide (see link)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html#sec-Configuring_Static_Routes_Using_nmcli) says that the following syntax should be used to assign a subnet to a gateway:

```
nmcli connection modify eth0 +ipv4.routes “192.168.122.0/24  10.0.0.1”
```

**How do I adjust the above to accommodate the `255.255.255.248` Subnet Mask and the `aa.aa.aaa.aa6` Default Gateway given by an internet service provider?**  Something like:

```
nmcli connection modify eth0 +ipv4.routes “255.255.255.248  aa.aa.aaa.aa6”
```

Note that:

1. the subnet is given in two different formats.
   a. The RHEL7 Networking Guide gives the subnet in the format `192.168.122.0/24`, while
   b. the internet service provider gives the subnet in the format `255.255.255.248`.
2. What is more,
   a.  the RHEL7 Networking Guide gives the gateway as a **private IP**, while
   b.  the internet service provider gives the gateway as a **public IP**.

For reference, a Windows laptop is able to connect to the internet and be recognized as one of the 5 valid IP addresses by giving the above information using the following steps:

```
1.  Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center    
2.  Click “Change Adapter Settings”  
3.  Right click on “Ethernet 2” connection and click on “Properties”  
4.  Select “Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)”  
5.  Then click on “Properties” Button to open the target dialog box:  
    a.  In the default state, the “Obtain IP address automatically” option is checked  
    b.  To claim a specific IP instead, click “Use The Following IP Address” and enter the following information:  
            i.  IP Address:  aa.aa.aaa.aa1  
            ii. Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248  
            iii.    Default Gateway: aa.aa.aaa.aa6  
            iv. Preferred DNS Server: bb.bb.bb.bb  
            v.  Alternate DNS Server: bb.bb.cc.cc  
            vi. Check the “Validate Settings on Exit” option.  
            vii.    Click OK  
6.  Click on any other open dialog boxes to return computer to normal state
```

Comment: `nmcli connection modify eth0 +ipv4.routes “aa.aa.aaa.aa0/29  aa.aa.aaa.aa6”`.  The RHEL guide assumes you are on a private network, whereas you are using a public IP range, that's all.